# Definition of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{X}}$-modules over a stack $\mathcal{X}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand\Sch{\mathrm{Sch}}$For a stack $\mathcal{X}$ in $(\Sch/S)_{\textrm{ét}}$, there is a site $(\Sch/\mathcal{X})_{\textrm{ét}}$ whose objects are $(T,t)$, where $T$ is an étale $X$-scheme and $t\in \mathcal{X}(T)$. A cover is a set of maps $\{(T_i,t_i)\to (T,t)\}$ such that $\{T_i\to T\}$ is a cover.

There is a sheaf of rings $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{X}}$ over this site, defined by $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}((T,t))=\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)$.

On the other hand, we have the ring $\mathcal{O}$ on $(\Sch/S)_{\textrm{ét}}$, defined by $\mathcal{O}(T)=\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)$. The fibred category of $\mathcal{O}$-modules form a stack, denoted $\textrm{MOD}_\mathcal{O}$. (This is theorem 4.2.15 of Olsson's book, [Algebraic spaces and stacks](https://doi.org/10.1090/coll/062).)

The question is, does the category of $\mathcal{O}_\mathcal{X}$-modules correspond to the category of morphisms $\textrm{Hom}(\mathcal{X},\textrm{MOD}_\mathcal{O})$ between stacks in the big étale site?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the whole stack MOD_O is a not stack of groupoids (in the fibers of MOD_O over a given scheme there are not just isomorphisms). (Unless this is already implicit in the definition by Olsson) So perhaps you have to take only the sub-fibered-category with only isos. Also, are you considering Hom(X,MOD_O) as morphisms of *fibered* categories (over Sch/S) or just morphisms of 'abstract' categories?

Comment: I am talking about them as a morphism of fibred categories.
Sorry my bad, MOD_O just satisfies descent

Comment: (Sorry I made a mess with editing the comment. I just meant maybe in Olsson's definition of MOD_O it's already implicit you've to only consider isos)

Comment: It is just a technicality anyways. If the stack is fibred in groupoids, then morphisms which are not isomorphisms in MOD_O will be ignored.